# Object reference not set to an instance of an object while starting Windows Service on button Click

Tags: c#, nullpointerexception, windows-services

I am trying to start and stop the windows service using button click on Windows Form application but as soon as i clicked on start button it is giving following error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here is my source code of the windows form application

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string svcStatus;
    ServiceController myService;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ServiceController myService = new ServiceController();
        myService.ServiceName = "ServiceName";
        svcStatus = myService.Status.ToString();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (svcStatus == "Stopped")
        {
            myService.Start();   // START the service if it is already Stopped

            string svcStatusWas = "";  
            while (svcStatus != "Running")
            {
                if (svcStatus != svcStatusWas)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Status: " + svcStatus);
                }

                svcStatusWas = svcStatus;

                myService.Refresh();
                svcStatus = myService.Status.ToString();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Service Started!!");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (svcStatus == "Running")
        {                
            myService.Stop();   // STOP the service if it is already Running

            string svcStatusWas = "";   
            while (svcStatus != "Stopped")
            {

                svcStatusWas = svcStatus;

                myService.Refresh();    
                svcStatus = myService.Status.ToString();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Service Stopped!!");
        }
    }

}
```

svcStatus i am getting stopped.Please help me.

Comment: Show some stack trace please.

Comment: @wiero myService.Start();

Comment: @Crono System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=ManageCapturingService

Comment: @DavidKhaykin what can be the possible solution?

Comment: That's not the stack trace, friend. This is: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Pranav actually I think ColinM's answer below shows the problem, I was wrong and didn't catch that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Form1() you have:

```
    ServiceController myService = new ServiceController();
    myService.ServiceName = "ServiceName";
    svcStatus = myService.Status.ToString();
```

which declares a local instance of ServiceController.  The click handlers are using the class member myService that is never being initialised.

Change the first of the above three lines to

```
    myService = new ServiceController();
```

and it should work.